# Compare with Latest Version in VS 2019

Tags: tfs

I have VS 2017 and VS 2019 installed on my computer. When I compare my changed code in VS 2019 Team Explorer's Pending Changes window, the differences are shown in VS 2017. That is as soon as I choose *Compare with Latest Version* option from context menu, VS 2017 is started and differences are shown in VS 2017. Is it something that I have to change in VS 2019 settings or VS2109 is supposed to work like this?

Comment: Hi MBK, any update on this issue, did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I did not try your solution as I thought I might need to reinstall all VS extensions after VS reset as mentioned in the link you provided. I would not like to have my VS extensions lost in the middle of the project that I am working on at the moment. I'll try your solution later when the project work is not over stressed like now. Thank you for your suggestion anyway!

Comment: Sure, thanks for your kindly response. Once you are free and finish the test, please feel free to share the result here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not an expected behavior.

Have tested VS2019 with either VS2017 or VS 2015 installed, both worked properly.

This strange behavior may related to cache. I was wondering if your target Path used to  open under VS2017 in your environment. Or something cached in VS2017.

[image]

Please try to [clear TFS cache and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) which may do the trick. First with TFS cache, if not work then with VS cache.

Comment: The error was automatically fixed when I deleted my user profile. Deleting my  profile was not related to this question. The profile was enormously big and I  decided to renew it from scratch. As a collateral result, VS error was fixed itself.

Comment: Hi @MBK Thanks for your kindly update. Glad to hear your issue fixed. According to your description, kind like some cache on machine or somewhere else(enormously big profile). To be honest, for this strange behavior, it's also hard and little value to dig into the root cause. You could move your comment to reply and mark it as an answer. Alternatively, if you think the information I provided was helpful or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer which will also help others in the community. In case they get stuck in similar situation.